# How can I solve this youtube-dl 429

Tags: ubuntu, youtube, youtube-dl

root@celenhosting04:~# youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdA8Dzk-JAM
[youtube] ZdA8Dzk-JAM: Downloading webpage
**ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.**

root@celenhosting04:~#

Help me please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube error HTTP 429 - Too Many Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918835/youtube-error-http-429-too-many-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--cookies option`, for example

`--cookies /path/to/cookies/file.txt`

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#http-error-429-too-many-requests-or-402-payment-required
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#how-do-i-pass-cookies-to-youtube-dl